# how to write linq to sql with lambda for this sql query

Tags: linq, lambda

hi friends please help me out to get out of this um new to linq with lambda

```
select cn from color,related
where cid in (select ciid from related where iid=2)
```

Comment: three tables with following schema

Comment: color(colorid,cn),related(rid,ciid,iid),product(iid,iname,etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how the relations are set up, the best I can do is free hand, something like;

```
(from c in db.color
 from r in db.related
 where c.cid == r.ciid && r.iid == 2
 select c).Distinct();
```

or

```
from c in db.color
where (from r in db.related where r.iid==2 select r.ciid).Contains(c.cid)
select c;
```

Comment: its just returning a one color;soo this is how my relations has been setup  color 1 to many with related

Comment: items one to many with items..simply i just want to get available item color for an item

Comment: @user2582841 If it's supposed to return a single color, just use `SingleOrDefault` at the end instead of `Distinct()`, that'll get the single color or `null` if none exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below expression

```
(from i in dbcontext.color
where (from j in  dbcontext.color where j.iid==2 select j.ciid).contains(i.cid)
select i)
```